# How to request a specific URI with curl

Tags: curl

I want this request:

```
GET http://localhost:9999 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Host: example.com
```

How can I get this with `curl`?
This would require to set the Host and requested URI individually, but I only know the `curl host/uri` notation...

Answer (score 4):

You can set additional headers with `curl` using the `-H` option:

```
curl -H 'Host: example.com' -H 'Accept: */*' http://localhost:9999
```